# There are a lot of notation websites. But where to find notations with taal/timing?

Tags: indian-classical, bansuri

(sorry if i am phrasing the quesion badly, I am beginner)

Summary: I am looking for notations like [this](https://imgur.com/a/peR1Jzj)

So I am learning song (Vande mataram) on my bansuri after practicing alankar. But in all websites notations are without taal or the timing. Even in youtube videos the notations are incorrect. Its very frustrating.

Can someone tell me any book or website where I can get notation like [this](https://imgur.com/a/peR1Jzj)

Comment: I'm afraid questions of the "help me find a ___" type aren't covered here. You can ask in the chat room, though; there's a room specifically for indian music, where this question already appears because of its tags: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132745/saptak